# How to set default' => $current_user->user_login

Tags: users

If i add new post, the current user i selected and saved. Now i have imported dummy data via XML import, and i need after editing the post, save the current-actually logged user.

screen here : 
ibb.co/hrGUGF 
ibb.co/fXZGwF

original:

```
<?php    
    return array(
        'author' => array(
            'label'        => __('Author', 'ait-toolkit'),
            'type'         => 'select-dynamic',
            'dataFunction' => 'AitItemCpt::fillAuthorMetabox',
            'default'      => array(),
            'capabilities' => true,
        ),
    );
```

Modified code:

```
<?php

global $user_login;
get_currentuserinfo();
return array(
    'author' => array(
        'label' => __('Author', 'ait-toolkit'),
        'type' => 'select-dynamic',
        'dataFunction' => 'AitItemCpt::fillAuthorMetabox',
        'default' => $current_user->user_login,
        'capabilities' => true,
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear to me but here's a version of your code which you may try:

```
<?php
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
return array(
    'author' => array(
        'label' => __('Author', 'ait-toolkit'),
        'type' => 'select-dynamic',
        'dataFunction' => 'AitItemCpt::fillAuthorMetabox',
        'default' => $current_user->ID, // or try changing it to $current_user->user_login if it doesn't work
        'capabilities' => true,
    )
);
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for answer. I tried, but its the same.
ibb.co/hrGUGF
ibb.co/fXZGwF

Comment: not replaced to logged user, need to select it manually with dropdown menu (with users)